# "Add to here" is not visible in page editor mode

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

When I click on "Component" in Page Editor mode I don't see "Add to here" for most of the components. I can see it for just one component which is not desired. I want it for all the components. I checked the properties, "Editable" is checked for it. Also placeholder settings are fine. Please suggest.

Comment: You tagged this as both Sitecore 6 and 7.  Can you be more specific as to which version you're using?

Comment: if you are using score, then please try reinstall the package

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing at least one `Add to here`, that means that you've got the Page Editor in the correct `Designing` view in Page Editor.

You say that your "placeholder settings are fine", but does the `Placeholder Key` match exactly the ID of the placeholder that you have in your rendering?  Additionally, have you specified the `Allowed Controls` that can be placed in the placeholder?